# How to convert a char to uppercase without using toupper function

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, uppercase, lowercase

Recently I've seen a piece of code that converts a char to lowercase, and if it's already a lowercase it stays the same.

```
char c = 'A';
c |= ' ';
//c -> 'a'
```

I'm trying to write a code that can convert a char to uppercase without using the [toupper](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/toupper/) function.

Currently the most simple way that i can think of is the code below.

```
char c = 'a';
c = (c | ' ') - ' ';
//c -> 'A'
```

So I'm wondering if there's a code which is more straightforward than this, and can achieve the same results.

Any help is appreciated.

**Quick explanation of the first code block**

```
Char | ASCII Code
' '  | 13
'A'  | 65
'a'  | 97
```

and the `or` operator for bit manipulation

```
   01000001 (char 'A')
Or 00100000 (char ' ')
 = 01100001 (char 'a')
----------------------
   01100001 (char 'a')
Or 00100000 (char ' ')
 = 01100001 (char 'a')
```

Comment: is using the difference between lower and upper case an option? see http://www.asciitable.com/ for the offset between A a B b etc.

Comment: `How to convert a char to uppercase in a simple way` The simplest way is to use std::toupper. `I'm trying to write a code that can convert a char to uppercase without using the toupper function.` Oh well, there goes that idea. In that case you'll need to consult the documentation of your target platform about the used encoding.

Comment: @OP:  Why do you think that there is a `toupper` function?  The answer to that question is the reason why you **should** be using `toupper`.  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper  See the two different results when the locale changes?

Comment: Yes, you're right, I really didn't thought much about the encoding...

Comment: To emphasize the point others have made, your encoding is probably not ASCII.

Comment: But actually this is just a code written to play with ASCII code, the method I show is definitely not for other encoding.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The inverse operation of `OR` is `AND` with the complement.

```
char c = 'a';
c &= ~' ';
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/TyOS69)

Explanation:

```
    01100001 (char 'a')
AND 11011111 (~ char ' ')
  = 01000001 (char 'A')
```

Answer (score 2):

A very intuitive and semi-readable way is to use character subtraction:

**<kbd>[Live on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2bfa9e7d3bcedc56)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>

char uppercase(char bla)
{
    return bla -('a'-'A');
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << uppercase('a') << '\n';
}
```

Note this only works on `a-z`, and the rest will need special treatment with some `if`s. I strongly suggest using `std::toupper` or a more unicode-aware version.

Answer (score 0):

A Better approach without the ASCII would be

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int length(char arr[])
{
    int i= 0;
    while(arr[i]!='\0')
    {
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}
char convertCase(char a)
{
    if(a>='a' && a<='z')
    {
        //isLowerCase
        a = 'A' + (a - 'a'); 
    }
    else if(a>='A' && a<='Z')
    {
        //isUpperCase
        a = 'a' + (a - 'A');
    }
    return a;
}
int main()
{
    char arr[1000]={ };
    cin.getline(arr,990);
    int length1 = length(arr);
    for(int i =0;i<length1;i++)
    {
        arr[i] = convertCase(arr[i]);   
    }
    for(int i =0;i<length1;i++)
    {
        cout<<arr[i];   
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "without the ASCII"? `a>='a' && a<='z'` implies ASCII or some charsets with contigous `'a'` to `'z'`